# de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.ImpExException[HY--1] Exception in Hybris ImpEx

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I am getting de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.**ImpExException**[HY--1] Exception when I try and run this ImpEx code below. I have specified the atomictype property as java.time.LocalDate in my items.xml file.

```
INSERT_UPDATE ExtendedEmployee;uid[unique=true];Employee_id[unique=true];Department(code);DateOfBirth
;Jas;67890;HR;1997-10-23
```

Items.xml file:

```
<atomictypes>
    <atomictype class="java.time.LocalDate"
        extends="java.lang.Object" autocreate="true" generate="false" />
</atomictypes>
.......
.......
.......
<itemtype code="ExtendedEmployee" extends="Employee"
            generate="false" autocreate="true">

            <attributes>

                <attribute type="java.lang.String"
                    qualifier="Employee_Id">
                    <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true"
                        optional="false" />
                    <persistence type="property" />
                </attribute>

                <attribute type="DepartmentType" qualifier="Department">
                    <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true"
                        optional="false" />
                    <persistence type="property" />
                </attribute>

                <attribute type="java.lang.Boolean"
                    qualifier="ActiveStatus">
                    <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" />
                    <persistence type="property" />
                    <defaultvalue>java.lang.Boolean.TRUE</defaultvalue>
                </attribute>

                <attribute type="java.time.LocalDate" qualifier="DateOfBirth">
                    <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true"
                        optional="false" />
                    <persistence type="property" />
                </attribute>

                <attribute type="java.lang.Integer" qualifier="Age">
                    <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" />
                    <persistence type="dynamic"
                        attributeHandler="ageHandler" />
                </attribute>

            </attributes>

        </itemtype>
```

Comment: Have you updated the running system ? (you can do it via `hac`)

Comment: I updated the system using HAC but still, I am getting exceptions

Comment: Can you update the question by adding your ExtendedEmployee definition from items.xml please?

Comment: Updated the items.xml file

Comment: Can you check if the `Employee` type that you're extending doesn't have any required fields? ( attributes with **optional=false** modifier )

Comment: All the mandatory fields have been filled up. I think HSQL doesn't support the give data-type. I specified the data-type to be LocalDate for DateOfBirth. Once I change it to java.util.Date, works fine. But I wanted to try with the LocalDate and I started getting that Exception

Comment: Maybe the format for LocalDate is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment section, HSQL does not support the LocalDate as data-type. When changed to java.util.Date, it works fine.